# Open an external program as Administrator?

Tags: vb.net

I know I can make my program start with admin rights, but how do I open a different program with admin rights programmatically using vb.net?

example:
`Process.start.RunAsAdmin?("C:\Test.exe")`

How do I open Test.exe as an admin from vb.net?
I know in the property settings of Test.exe I can choose to "Run as Admin" but I would like to do it from vb.net, as Test.exe was just an example and will not be included from my vb.net project.

Comment: I think an alternative would be to run your vb.net project output exe as admin and then subsequently call to c:\Test.exe should also run as admin automatically.

Comment: Set the ProcessStartInfo.Verb property to "runas"

Comment: @TheShooter I'll test it out later as im not home atm, although I don't think it worked when I attempted to open a batch file which needed Admin Privileges. (I mainly need it for a batch file), I remember trying but I can't recall if I made my vb.net program run as admin after or before running the .bat

Comment: @HansPassant How do I do that?  This isn't for the vb.net project, it's for a batch file which runs outside of my vb.net program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Hans already wrote in his comment, you can start a process with elevated rights by creating a `ProcessInfo` object and set its relevant properties:

```
Dim startInfo as new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\";
startInfo.FileName = "Test.exe";
startInfo.Verb = "runas";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```